# robot description problem!

Tags: ros, rviz, urdf, robot-description, joint-state-publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have written a robot description for our robot which is consist of urdf of a pantilt,kinect and the robot's base platform!

The problem is that when i am running robot_description in a remote pc and pantilt controller in robot's pc i am getting below warning in rviz:

"there is no transform from map to openni_depth_frame"(also for all of other frames which is mounted on pantilt frame).

In RVIZ i can see that the joints between pantilt and kinect is attached properly but the position of kinect's frames is wrong! their position is not updated and their position is 0,0,0!

The pantilt controller publishes joint states of pantilt and i can get pantilt joint states in properly. When i am running robot's description and pantilt controller on the same side every thing works fine! (I am sure about the configurations of my network communication ).

Any Idea?

thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35187/robot-description-problem!/) by [Alireza](https://answers.ros.org/users/1637/alireza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 717 on 2012-05-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2012-05-29**:
Can you upload the URDF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem probably is in the fact that there is no link named "openni_depth_frame", just "camera_depth_frame". I'm not sure why that would work when its all on the same machine though.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2012-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1